# CSS - Vertical text overlap another div content

Tags: css, overlap, direction

the following div contains vetical text (is the page title at left of the page). The problem is that the vertical text overflow its div and overlap another content div. I've made something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.vertical_text{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    display:block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    direction:rtl;
    margin:0;
    color:#000;
    padding:0 10px 0 0;
}
</style>

<!--left sidebar-->
<div class="vertical_text" style="width:30%;">
    Vertical text that overlap bottom div content
</div>
<!--right sidebar-->
<div style="width:70%;">
    Main page content
</div>

<!--Footer-->
<div style="width:100%;">
    Footer div. Content in this div is covered by vertical text
</div>
```

How can I prevent overlap others divs content? I need that the footer div move down to prevent its content overlap.

Thanks for help,
Victor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT AFTER COMMENT

I added some Jquery script to manage the dynamic height. And move the rotate div in another one to maintain split 30%/70%

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3YV7r/1/)

CSS

```
.vertical_text{
    direction:rtl;
    margin:0;
    color:#000;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.rotate{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

HTML

```
<!--left sidebar-->
<div style="float:left;width:30%">
    <div class="vertical_text" >
        Vertical text that overlap bottom div content
    </div>
</div>
<!--right sidebar-->
<div style="width:70%;float:left">
    Main page content
</div>
<div style="clear:both">
</div>    
<!--Footer-->
<div style="width:100%;margin-top:10px;">
    Footer div. Content in this div is covered by vertical text
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function() {
   $(".vertical_text").height($(".vertical_text").width());
    $(".vertical_text").addClass("rotate");
});
```

Comment: It works fine, but in my case, the vertical text is a dynamic text (is the page title and could be modified) so, the text lengh may be different in each case. I can't define a "static" height in the vertical_text div because the text lengh will be different. How can I "automatically" adjust div height to vertical text (the vertical text must be white-space:nowrap;)?

Comment: Yes! that's the way! But in some cases, the text in vertical_text div is longer than its div width (the text is nowrap, so it overflows the div). With jquery function we define the new height as div width, but the text is longer, then we rotate and text overlap the bottom div. How can we define the new vertical_text height as text lenght (instead width div)? Thanks